# ¿Está bien almacenar datos de tarjetas de crédito encriptadas en una base de datos?

Tags: seguridad, base-de-datos

Necesito armar un módulo de facturación por servicios ofrecidos por internet. La idea es ofrecer un servicio que se abona por mes automáticamente sin que el cliente tenga la necesidad de pagar cada mes.

¿Cuales son las mejores practicas para este caso?

Mi idea apunta a guardar los datos de la tarjeta en la base de datos junto a los datos del cliente, encriptados.

Desconozco por completo este tema. ¿Alguna orientación?

Answer (score 4):

El riesgo de guardar información de tarjetas de crédito es tan grande que hay un 
estandard de seguridad al respecto: [PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). Incluso si no sufres ataques, si no sigues el estandard (o las normas de [tu lugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard#Mandated_compliance)) puedes tener problemas legales.

Si realmente necesitas recuperar los datos de la tarjeta de un cliente para futuras transacciones, guardarlo en tu DB no es fácil. Por supuesto, requiere 
encriptarlo, pero ¿dónde guardar la clave para desencriptarlo? Es complejo implementar esto de manera segura, y respetando el estandar (que, justamente,
contempla estos problemas). Y como dicen [aquí](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/storing-credit-cards-for-automatic-payments) (traduzco)

> ni pienses en almacenar tarjetas de crédito sin entender lo básico de PCI-DSS

Para guardar la clave de encriptación de manera segura terminarás por necesitar un soporte especial de hardware, o al menos un servidor (realmente remoto) de seguridad que se encarga exclusivamente de eso (de proveer claves)... Es complejo.

En los escenarios típicos (y modestos) en la actualidad, la opción más razonable suele ser no guardar los datos en nuestra propia DB, sino delegarlo a servicios online de terceros (APIs remotas de pasarelas de pago, etc).

Más info en inglés [aquí](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37550/storing-credit-cards) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328922/saving-credit-card-information-in-mysql-database).

Answer (score 1):

No veo seguro que por tu cuenta guardes los datos de pago de un cliente, deberias evaluar el uso de servicios de terceros que sean reconocidos internacionalmente y ofrescan un enlace seguro para realizar el pago.

Apunto a que uses servicio como ser `PayPal`

Puede usar las librerias que este brinda para interactuar con tu aplicacion

[PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK)

de esta forma brindas al cliente un medio seguro y confiable para realizar los pagos por el servicio que le brindas.

Si la idea es que pague todos los meses, generarias desde código un pago que el cliente debe autorizar para que se confirme la operacion. De forma arbitraria tu no puedes generarle un cobro por el hecho de tener sus datos, salvo que realices alguna operacion por medio de un banco y se cree un debito automático, pero bueno alli hay un tercero que reemplazaria a paypal que seráa al entidad bancaria.

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente las webs de reservas de hoteles o alquiler de vehículos almacenan los datos de la tarjeta de crédito del cliente para garantizar la reserva y cobrar el importe adeudado en caso de que el cliente no se presente.

Estas empresas reciben los datos de la tarjeta por e-mail y si no te presentas al hotel o a recoger el automóvil te lo cobran posteriormente con el datáfono. En algunos casos ni siquiera te piden la tarjeta al llegar al establecimiento porque ya tienen tus datos y lo cobran directamente.

No obstante, si deseas almacenar algún tipo de dato comprometedor para gestionar autopagos o situaciones similares, deberías de avisar al cliente y especificarlo en las condiciones de uso del sitio. Esto lo llevan haciendo algún tiempo algunas webs de venta del tipo aliexpress.

Answer (score -1):

En cierta ocasión tuve que programar el "almacenamiento" de la tarjeta. Pero no se guardaba como tal. La pasarela de pago nos dió la opción de guardar ese dato par que el cliente puedises pagar sin tener que introducir la tarjeta siempre pero lo que se guardaba era un token que nos mandaba la pasarela de pago. Dudo que eso sea legal.
Para explicarlo mejor:
-En el formulario donde se le pasan los datos para pagar, como la cantidad, moneda, clave del comercio, etc... se mandaba la tarjeta. En la respuesta de la pasarela nos daba un token para almacenarlo en la base de datos y asi en las compras sucesivas de dicho cliente se le pasaba ese token.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que he visto que suelen hacer algunas apps y páginas es y como idea no es mala:

Almacenar número de tarjeta + fecha caducidad, pero no el código de 3 cifras CCV creo que se llama, y cada vez que el cliente quiere pagar, tiene que introducir el ccv.

Y también, en la app o web, ellos a la hora de mostrar el número de tarjeta sólo muestran los últimos 6 dígitos de la tarjeta.

Saludos.

Comment: no he dicho que sea una idea a aplicar si no lo que he visto.
No me matéis a dislikes X).