# ¿Se puede almacenar los 4 últimos dígitos de una tarjeta de pago?

Tags: seguridad, tpv

Buenas tardes.

Ando buscando información y no encuentro nada que me termine de aclarar.

Estamos implantando *Pago con Referencia* por RedSyS. De los datos que quiero almacenar, querría tener un nº de referencia del token para el cliente, para que identificara de algún modo la tarjeta que quisiera utilizar o eliminar de mi sistema, por ejemplo, en el caso que tuviera varias.

Me he leido un buen cacho del **PCI DSS 2016**, pero no me lo deja muy claro. Se que el PAN debo dejarlo ilegible en la BBDD, pero manteniendo un sistema de seguridad que no es viable para mi proyecto... No obstante, ¿puedo almacenar al menos los últimos 4 números de la tarjeta, aunque fueran encriptados?

¿Puedo tener algún dato que pueda almacenar para este fin y que sea identificativo para el cliente? Ante todo, quiero utilizar los medios legales y no quiero desarrollar nada que pueda meterme en líos.

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Creo que eso va de acuerdo a las leyes del país donde se almacenen los datos y del país de la empresa desarrolladora.

Comment: hasta donde se, el PCI DSS es el organismo internacional que regula esto, pero leer la guia ya de por si es complicado. He visto tambien éste hilo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4030/est%C3%A1-bien-almacenar-datos-de-tarjetas-de-cr%C3%A9dito-encriptadas-en-una-base-de-dat pero no me concreta mucho. Como dato, el desarrollo y la BBDD son en España.

Comment: Eso lo hacen todos. Yo estoy seguro de que es posible hacerlo sin problema.